# Image Processing Operations inside R shiny server.R

Tags: r, image-processing, shiny

I'm currently working on image processing application using `R Shiny` It uploads an image using file upload and then I need to read the image to do the image processing operations. `server.R` file is as follows.

```
library(shiny)
library(EBImage)  
library(imager)
library(jpeg)
function(input, output) {

  observe({
      file_path <- input$files
      if (is.null(file_path))
        return(NULL)
      file_path$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", file_path$datapath)      

      img <- readImage(file_path$datapath)
      equalized <- equalize(img,range = c(0, 1), levels = 256)

      output$text <- renderText({
        file_path$datapath          
      })
      output$img <- renderImage({
        list(src = file_path$datapath,
             contentType = "image/jpg",
             width = "50%",
             height = "auto",
             alt = "This is alternate text")
    })

  })  

}
```

But this gives me the following error.

```
Warning: Error in readImage: Please supply at least one filename.
Stack trace (innermost first):
    57: readImage
    56: observerFunc
```

Comment: Check your `file_path$datapath` value before the `readImage` line.

Comment: Not relevant to your question but creating output inside an `observe` is sort of odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to plot an equalized image using raster method. Here are some tips/tricks:

1. You put everything inside an observer which is a pretty bad idea, so I got rid of that.
2. Use `req()` when checking whether a file is uploaded, UI is rendered, etc instead of an if statement. `

> `if (is.null(file_path)) return(NULL)`

3. There is no need to assign `input$files` to a variable, you can call `input$files$datapath`. Also `gsub()` is not needed in this case.

> ```
> file_path <- input$files
>       file_path$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", file_path$datapath)
> ```

4. `equalized` is calculated, but you don't use it anywhere.

### Solution

1. Checking with `req()` whether a file is uploaded.
2. Get the extension of the file (splitting by `.`, getting the last element)
3. Plot the equalized image using the `display()` function with `method = "raster"`.
4. Print `datapath` which points to a temp dir/file

See:

```
library(shiny)
library(EBImage)  
library(imager)
library(jpeg)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("files", "Upload a file"),
  plotOutput("img"),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$img <- renderPlot({ 
    req(input$files)
    st <- strsplit(input$files$name, split = "[.]")[[1]]
    extension <- st[length(st)]
    display(equalize(readImage(input$files$datapath, type = extension), range = c(0, 1), levels = 256), method = "raster")
  })
  output$txt <- renderText({
    input$files$datapath
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using EBImage we can load an image into Rshiny and use it for further processing. Below code allows the user to upload an image and then same is displayed on shiny screen back.

```
library(shiny)
library(EBImage)  
upload_image <- list()

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file1", "Upload an Image"),
  plotOutput("img")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$img <- renderPlot({ 
    req(input$file1)
    upload_image[[1]] <- readImage(input$file1$datapath)
    plot(upload_image[[1]])
   })
}


shinyApp(ui , server)
```